# Accelerate code passes intepreter but fails under CUDA

Tags: haskell, cuda, numeric, accelerate-haskell

I have been trying to write a function in that will take a histogram of a vector using the accelerate library.  I recognize that histograms aren't the idea case for GPU processing, but I'm generating a fairly large dataset from a small seed and it would be nice if it could be reduced to a few kilobyte array before transferring it back to main memory.

The code that I've come up with is below.  It takes a number of output bins then then creates a new array where the values of a[x] is the number of occurrences of x in xs

```
hist :: A.Exp Int -> A.Acc (A.Vector Int) -> A.Acc (A.Vector Int)
hist bins xs = A.permute
               (const (+1))
               (A.fill (A.index1 bins) 0)
               (A.index1 . (xs A.!))
               xs
```

The code appears to run properly under the Accelerate interpreter.  However, if I try to call it through accelerate-cuda, I get the following error message.

```
./Data/Array/Accelerate/CUDA/State.hs:85:9: (unhandled): CUDA Exception: unspecified launch failure
```

My question is two-fold.  First, what am I doing that causes CUDA to fail?  Second, is there a better way to take a histogram through Accelerate?

Comment: You've checked that CUDA as such runs fine, have you?

Comment: If I remove `hist` from the calculation, the rest of the function runs under CUDA without issue.

Comment: @user640078. did you ever find a solution to this? Is there an answer to add here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Accelerate (and/or underlying change in CUDA) which has [now been fixed](https://github.com/AccelerateHS/accelerate/issues/280). Apologies for taking so long to get to it, this slipped off my radar.